# How to create a hyperlink in PowerPoint using Powershell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am a freshman for powershell. I am write some code to new a PowerPoint file and insert some hyperlinks to local files. But there is no sample code  that can be found.

Comment: Look up a good MS Office Library, get some .NET code examples and re-write them as PowerShell script.

Comment: @marsze Would you kindly consider adding some reference links to what you consider to be good MS Office Library .Net code?

Answer (score 0):

```
If (test-path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Classes\PowerPoint.Application) {
$powerPointFileName = "TestPowerPoint"
Write-Output "Microsoft PowerPoint installed. Start to create PowerPoint file:$powerPointFileName"
$PPT = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$PPT.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$slideType = "microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppSlideLayout" -as [type]
$presentation = $PPT.Presentations.Add()
$newSlide = $presentation.Slides.add($presentation.Slides.Count + 1, 3)
$newSlide.Shapes.title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text ="Test Update Hyperlinks"
$newSlide.shapes.item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Link 1"
$newSlide.shapes.item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Address = "C:\readme.doc"
$newSlide.shapes.item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Link 2"
$newSlide.shapes.item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Address = "C:\test\readme.doc"

$presentation.SaveAs("C:\$powerPointFileName")
$presentation.Close()
$PPT.Quit()
$PPT = $null
Get-Process "PowerPNT" | Stop-Process -Force
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
} else {
Write-Output "No PowerPoint is installed. Cancel to create PowerPoint file."
}
```